# vtk.js and cornerstone interaction for rendering Dicom

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to directly specify the values ​​of Rescale Intercept / Slope / Type (vtk.js) for the correct rendering of a dicom image?
I know that if I used itk for reading, these values ​​would be taken into account, but I use the cornerstone for loading and initial drawing images, and for MPR I try to use vtk.js.

In my case the rendered images looks very bright,
I thought that there simply wasn’t enough setting window level values, but when setting values ​​obtained from cornerstone (window width window center)

```js
        const window = 400; // cornerstone image.windowWidth = 400
        const center = 40; // cornerstone image.windowCenter = 40

        const mappingRangeLower = center - window / 2;
        const mappingRangeUpper = center + window / 2;

        volumeActor.getProperty()
          .getRGBTransferFunction(0)
          .setMappingRange(mappingRangeLower, mappingRangeUpper);
```

the picture is still not drawn correctly.

I thought maybe the values ​​of Rescale Intercept / Slope / Type are not set or maybe I'm missing something. Please help resolve the issue.